# Changing client web part properties Title/Description with diffrent languages

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-online, visual-studio, localization

We want to change our client web part Title and Description depending on Supported locales(languages).

The Validation checklist for apps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938162(v=office.15).aspx
"I have specified the supported locales for my app."

We are using these Supported locales

```
<SupportedLocale CultureName="en-US" /> 
<SupportedLocale CultureName="sv-SE" />
```

and these Resources

```
Resources.en-US.resx
Resources.sv-SE.resx
Resources.resx
```

Inside them we use "App_Title", "AppPart_Title", "AppPart_Description".

Inside the Appmanifest.xml we use the App_Title to change the Title of the title tag, this works like it should.

```
<title>$Resources:App_Title</title>
```

But when we try the same thing inside our Client Web part we get a string "$Resources:AppPart_Title" and the same with "Resources:AppPart_Description" instead of the value.

```
<ClientWebPart Name="App" Title="$Resources:AppPart_Title" Description="$Resources:AppPart_Description" DefaultWidth="300" DefaultHeight="200">
```

We found most of the code from "How to: Localize apps for SharePoint".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179919(v=office.15).aspx
and the sample "SharePoint 2013: Localize the app web, host web, and remote components of an app". http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Bookstore-328060fc#content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our problem.

We were using Visual Studio 2012 and somehow 2012 version doesnt support $Resources:AppPart_Title inside client web part xml. When you publish the app you get the ".app" file and the "$Resources" inside client web part xml become "string type" instead of a link to a variable inside the Resource file.

We solved this by upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.